# Is it ok to define a prototype function on Object in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, function, object, prototype

```javascript
Object.prototype.doSomething = function(p) {
    this.innerHTML = "<em>bar</em>";
    this.style.color = "#f00";
    alert(p);
};

document.getElementById("foo").doSomething("Hello World");
```

`<div id="foo"><strong>foo</strong></div>`

The code above works fine.

But I remember that I saw this somewhere: `Do not mess with native Object.` well, something like that.

So is it ok to define a prototype function on **Object**? Are there any reasons that I should not do this?

Comment: Is this for a library others will be consuming? Or for your own application code?

Comment: I'm writing a small library that others may be using as well. As the answers suggested below, I think that I should not be doing this, no matter who the code is written for.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The only safe way to add to `Object.prototype` is to use the ES5 method [`Object.defineProperty`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty) to create a *non-enumerable* property:

```
Object.defineProperty(Object.prototype, 'doSomething', {
    value: function(p) { ... },
    enumerable: false,  // actually the default
});
```

This ensures that the new property doesn't appear if you do `for (key in object)`.

Note that this function cannot be reliably shimmed because non-enumerable properties didn't exist in previous versions of ECMAScript / JavaScript.

In any event, if your method only applies to HTML page elements, you would be better adding this to `Element.prototype` instead of to `Object.prototype`, although older (IE) browsers may complain if you do this.

Comment: Isn't [`hasOwnProperty`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty) a best practice now anyway though?

Comment: @RoatinMarth no, IMHO `hasOwnProperty` is _old_ best practise.  In an ES5 browser it should be unnecessary. Any code that uncleanly messes with `Object.prototype` should be banished.  Even jQuery omits the `hasOwnProperty` test and explicitly states that it'll fail if you use code that abuses it.

Comment: `non-enumerable properties don't exist in previous versions of Javascript.` which version do you mean by `previous`?

Comment: @user1643156 anything prior to ECMAScript 5.0

Comment: IE 6/7/8 supports only ECMAScript 3.0 (JavaScript 1.5). so I guess `Object.defineProperty` is not a cross-browser option for my problem.

Comment: @user1643156 no, not if you're stuck with supporting browsers that old.  Adding to `Element.prototype` might work in IE7/8 (but probably not IE6).

Answer (score 1):

Generally not a good idea.  That function is now available on *everything* in your app that uses the Object prototype(which is a lot) and will show up in functions that enumerate the Object proto.

A better option is to define a separate prototype:

```
function MyObject {
    ...
}

MyObject.prototype.doSomething = function() {
    ...
}

var myObj = new MyObject();
```

Answer (score 1):

If you add stuff to the object prototype, you lose the nice object iteration functionality using `for p in obj`, since enumerable properties you have added are iterated over as well **on all objects**.

For example:

```
Object.prototype.doSomething = function(p) {
    this.innerHTML = "<em>bar</em>";
    this.style.color = "#f00";
    alert(p);
};

for (p in {foo:"bar"}){
    console.log(p);
}

//foo
//doSomething
```

Unexpectedly, you will also get `doSomething` logged. To fix this, you will have to add a `hasOwnproperty` check when iterating over your object, but the risk here is that you could break other code that doesn't expect a plain object to have properties other than the ones specified in the literal.

Comment: since _enumerable_ properties you have added...

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to **call** a method, defined not as an object prototype method-

```
function doSomething(p) {
    this.innerHTML = "<em>"+p+"</em>";
    this.style.color = "#f00";
    alert(p);
};
```

//

```
doSomething.call(document.getElementById("foo"),"Hello World");
```